# Base64 image string into image file using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, base64, web-development-server

I need code to convert a base64 image string into an image file and write into local directory using PHP. I tried:

```php
function user_profile_photo(){
            $input = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
            $received = json_decode($input, true);
            $user_id = $received['user_id'];
            $img = $received['imagecode'];
            $imagedata = base64_decode($img);
            $image_path='uploads/images/'.$user_id;             
            $path = '/var/www/html/empengapp/uploads/images/'.$user_id;
            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                   mkdir($path, 0755, true);
             }

$new_name = date('ymd').time().'.jpg';
$pathwithfile = '/var/www/html/empengapp/uploads/images/'.$user_id.'/'.$new_name;
$success = file_put_contents($pathwithfile, $imagedata);
var_dump($imagedata);exit;




            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
                ->set_output(json_encode($resp, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
                ->_display();
                exit;
    }//end of function user_profile_photo
```

It is writing a file with given extension, but when you try to open file it shows an invalid file error.

Comment: Is it a valid encoded base64 from the original? ($img)

Comment: please show $img (but please share an example of a small image!). [edit] your question to add an example.

Comment: Yes it is valid base64 encode string which I am receiving on server. And decoding it into first line.

Comment: My image base64 string  is too long. You can use https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter to convert any file into base64 string online.

Comment: I know how to convert any file to base64, but to figure out what's wrong I wanted to see your file. You can upload your file to https://www.base64decode.org/ (under Decode files from Base64 format) to see if you base64 image is correct.

Comment: I already checked decoded code of base64 string on codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter and its converting my decoded string into image. Updated my question with full function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out the solution.

```html
        $pathwithfile = 'your file path with image name';//e.g '/uploads/test.jpg'

         $ifp = fopen( $pathwithfile, 'wb' ); 

       // split the string on commas
       // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
       // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
       $data = explode( ',', $imagedata );
       $success = fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );       // clean up the file resource
       fclose( $ifp );
```

I was sending over the API to PHP server. You need to encode your image base64 string and your image base64 string must include "data:image/jpeg;base64". We are splitting it on PHP server But don't think to send image base54 without "data:image/jpeg;base64".
But remember one thing you have to use image base64 including